# CASE vs Multiple UPDATE queries for large data sets - Performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, case, sql-update

For performance what option would be better for large data sets that are to be updated?

Using a CASE statement or Individual update queries?

CASE Example:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET field_name = 
CASE
    WHEN condition_1 THEN 'Blah'
    WHEN condition_2 THEN 'Foo'
    WHEN condition_x THEN 123
    ELSE 'bar'
END AS value
```

Individual Query Example:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET field_name = 'Blah' WHERE field_name = condition_1
UPDATE tbl_name SET field_name = 'Foo' WHERE field_name = condition_2
UPDATE tbl_name SET field_name = 123 WHERE field_name = condition_x
UPDATE tbl_name SET field_name = 'bar' WHERE field_name = condition_y
```

NOTE: About 300,000 records are going to be updated and the CASE statement would have about 10,000 WHEN conditions. If using the individual queries it's about 10,000 as well

Comment: "If using the individual queries it's about 10,000 as well" - perhaps a joined temp table would be a better idea....

Comment: +1 Mitch...didn't notice the scope when I wrote my answer.  In principle `CASE` will be more efficient but maybe not at that scale.

Comment: Interesting I had not thought of this approach, Thanks

Comment: When using option 2 you have to make sure to run everything in one transaction (no autocommit!) - in that case I'm inclined to believe there will no big difference between the two especially if field_name is indexed. But you will **have** to try for yourself. It's more or less impossible to give you a correct answer without having access to your system.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**The `CASE` version.**

This is because there is a good chance you are altering the same row more than once with the individual statements.  If row 10 has both `condition_1` and `condition_y` then it will need to get read and altered twice.  If you have a clustered index this means two clustered index updates on top of whatever the other field(s) that were modified were.

If you can do it as a single statement, each row will be read only once and it should run much quicker.

I changed a similar process about a year ago that used dozens of `UPDATE` statements in sequence to use a since `UPDATE` with `CASE` and processing time dropped about 80%.

Answer (score 0):

It seems logic to me that on the first option SQL Server will go through the table only once and for each row, it will evaluate the condition.

On the second, it will have to go through all table 4 times

So, for a table with 1000 rows, on the first option on the best case scenario we are talking about 1000 evaluations and worst case, 3000. 
On the second we'll always have 4000 evaluations

So option 1 would be the faster.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Mitch, try making a temp table filling it with all the data you need, make a different temp table for each column (field) you want to change. You should also add an index to the temp table(s) for added performance improvement.

This way your update statement becomes (more or less):

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET field_name = COALESCE((SELECT value FROM temp_tbl WHERE tbl_name.conditional_field = temp_tbl.condition_value), field_name),
    field_name2 = COALESCE((SELECT value FROM temp_tbl2 WHERE tbl_name.conditional_field2 = temp_tbl2.condition_value), field_name2)
```

and so on..

This should give you good performance while scaling up for large volumes of updates at once.